# insert problem in C#, using sqlcommand

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, insert

when I run this sql:

```
insert into table1(ID,Name) values ('10','Saeed');
```

it seems that the record has been inserted, and if I read the table using (`select * from table1`) it shows me the inserted record, but after closing the program, it disappears.

it's the code:

```
string constr="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|" +   
    "\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "insert into st (ID,Name) values ('10','saeed');", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Close();
```

I inserted some records in it manually, and when I read the database, the manually inserted records exist.

It is not a transaction problem wont be solved with a transaction!

Comment: Maybe you need to Commit the insertion?

Comment: SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction(); ... tran.Commit();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue sounds like you started a transaction and forgot to commit it.  However, if you are using the exact code you posted this is not a transaction problem because you are not using one.

That makes me think there is something funky going on with your connection string.

For kicks and giggles trying changing your connection string to something like this

```
Server=myServerName\theInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Comment: would you please write me the exact connection string, you can see mine in the question.

Comment: Initial Catalog=Database1;Data Source=<server name>;Integrated Security=True

Also try changing the User Instance=False in your current connection string.  The records are probably inserting per that user instance only.  That is probably why you do not see the new inserted records after you close the application.

Answer (score 2):

Guess:
You are working with SQL Server Express and "Database1.mdf" within your project is configured (in properties window) for "Copy to Output Directory" value "Always"

Comment: I have the same feeling. Let us know if this was the solution

Comment: Change the property to "If Newer" or "Don't copy". Whenever the file becomes copied, the data are lost.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify: "Initial Catalog=InstanceDB;" as well to make sure it does not create a new db name when you restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

error in your code itself 
its

`con.Close()`;

not

```
cmd.Close();
```

there is no close method for [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand_methods.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with pascal. Sounds like the transaction isn't being committed.

(Edited to provide clearer code block from my Comment below)

```
con.Open(); 
trans = con.BeginTransaction(); 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "insert into st (ID,Name) values ('10','saeed');", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
tran.Commit();
```

Comment: How to committee the insertion?

Comment: Well, basically it's something like:

   con.Open();
   trans = con.BeginTransaction();

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
   "insert into st (ID,Name) values ('10','saeed');", con);

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   tran.Commit();

This is off the top of my head.  You'll want to do some Googleing to confirm the details.