# Insert,update and delete data from Sql database using vb.net?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

This is my code for inserting data in the data table. When `Execute` i m getting the message "SUCCESS". But the data is not present in the data table.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim s As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=G:\ANDY\Dot Net.Practical\SQL DATA BASE\inserting4\inserting4\App_Data\location.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Dim sql As String
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        con = New SqlConnection(s)
        con.Open()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        sql = "insert into location(name,street,city)values(@name,@street,@city)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@street", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("SUCCESS")


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are missing an open connection string before `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert problem in C#, using sqlcommand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317868/insert-problem-in-c-using-sqlcommand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `Location`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Location;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...