# Database not being updated

Tags: c#, localdb

This is my code:

```
conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\\Users.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");
conn.Open();

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("update users set surname='simpson' where id=1", conn);
int i = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(i + "");

comm = new SqlCommand("select surname from users where id=1", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
MessageBox.Show(reader[0] + "");
conn.Close();
```

The ExecuteNonQuery returns 1 to show the database has been updated and the second query confirms it. But when I open the database in visual studio 2013, there are no changes, database still the same

Comment: See if any of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317868/insert-problem-in-c-using-sqlcommand) point you in the right direction.

Comment: You are either using a new database each time, or you have an open TransactionScope around that code section and you aren't committing it.

Comment: Thanks Grant and Danny, the database was set to copy to the output folder each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu mean, when you stop the program and Visual Studio throws away the copy of the database and resets it to the empty one then the data is gone? Yes, that is true.

Comment: YES, that is exactly what seems to be happening after my program stops.

Comment: Well, as I said - what happens is that the template databases is used in visual studio, and the program gets a new copy - so the editor can not see the data. works as planned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change your connectionstring, or refresh the database.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the database had been set to copy to the output folder each time